# CVBufferRelease crash after app change state from backgorund to foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, background

I'm using the following code in order to create a video given an array of images.
Everything works correctly. The code runs on a serial queue.
This code crash on CVBufferRelease(buffer) when the state app change from background to foreground. 
I have also verified that the buffer does not point to null.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgFrameData];
CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
buffer = [self newPixelBufferFromCGImage:[image CGImage] andSize:CGSizeMake(frameSize, frameSize)];

BOOL append_ok = NO;

while (!append_ok){
    if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
    {

      CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(i*timeBetweenFrame,(int32_t) TIMESCALE);
      CMTimeShow(frameTime); 
      append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
      if(buffer)
      {          
          CVBufferRelease(buffer);              
      }

      [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];
    }
    else
    {
       [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
    }
  }
```